# String to map conversion java

Tags: java, string, hashmap

Code:

```
 Map test = new HashMap<String,String>();
 test.put("1", "erica");
 test.put("2", "frog");
 System.out.println(test.toString());
```

This code gives output as :

```
 {1=erica, 2=frog}
```

I want this output to be again put in a map as key value-pair .
Any suggestions how can i implement this ?
Or is ther any predefined utility class for conversion of the output to `HashMap` again ?

Comment: There's no standard utility to de-serialize the string representation of a `Map` back into a `Map` object, so you'd have to build one yourself. The question is, why would you require that (as opposed to, say serialize to JSON or XML)?

Comment: `toString` output can change, you should not depend on it.

Comment: Agreed - consider serializing to/from JSON or something similar - just using the Jackson ObjectMapper will do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

For me a proper way would be to use a `JSON` parser like [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) since the way a `HashMap` is serialized is not meant to be parsed after such that if you use specific characters like `=` or `,` they won't be escaped which makes it unparsable.

**How to serialize a `Map` with `Jackson`?**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(myMap);
```

**How to deserialize a `String` to get a `Map` with `Jackson`?**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map map = mapper.readValue(contentToParse, Map.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this:

```
String[] tk = mystring.split(" |=");
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i < tk.length-1; i++)
{ 
  map.put(tk[i], tk[i]);
}
return map;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate the Java code filling the map, you may use something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<>();");
for(Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : test.entrySet())
{
    sb.append("\ntest.put(\"");
    sb.append(entry.getKey());
    sb.append("\", \"");
    sb.append(entry.getValue());
    sb.append("\");");
}
String string = sb.toString();
System.out.println(string);
```

But I agree with the comments, that in many applications a format such as JSON is more appropriate to serialize a map.

Note that the above solution does not escape strings, it only works if the strings don't contain characters like " or \n. If you need to handle these cases it will become more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
String out = test.toString();
Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap();
// remove the first and last "{", "}"
out = out.subString(1,out.size()-1)
String[] newOut = out.split(", ");
for (int i=0; i<newOut.length;i++){
    // keyValue is size of 2. cell 0 is key, cell 1 is value
    String[] keyValue = newOut.split("=");
    newMap.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
}
```

I haven't tested the code in java i just wrote from my mind. I hope it will work